# HttpWebRequests blocking UI thread from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest

I am doing multiple HttpWebRequests on Seaprate threads but my UI Thread is blocked almost all the time after I call `Start()` and I can't figure out why, here is the most important code:

```
private void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var todo = UrlStack.UrlPartitions.First();
        UrlStack.UrlPartitions.Remove(todo);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ScanSites), todo);
    }
}
private void ScanSites(object o)
{
    var ToDo = (List<string>)o;
    foreach (string Url in ToDo)
    {
        var state = MakeRequest(Url);
        var website = WebsiteProcessing.ProcessResponse(state);
        if (website != null)
        {
            Websites.Add(website);
            WebsitesCount++;
            this.UIThread(() => lblCrawledWebsites.Text = WebsitesCount.ToString());
        }
    }
}
private static RequestState MakeRequest(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    ...
    RequestState state = new RequestState();
    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    Stream responseStream = null;
    StreamReader sr = null;

    try
    {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        state.Request = (HttpWebRequest)request;
        state.Response = (HttpWebResponse)response;
        string strContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
        state.ResponseContent = new StringBuilder(strContent);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }

    finally
    {
        if (responseStream != null)
            responseStream.Close();
        if (sr != null)
            sr.Close();
        if (response != null)
            response.Close();
    }

    return state;
}
```

Comment: What is the implementation of this.UIThread(...)? You are updating a control in the UI thread, so how big is a ToDo? If it contains lots of lines, this means lots of updates, which means a slow UI. Can't you wait with updating the UI until you're done?

Comment: @Maarten UIThread checks if invoke is needed and invokes if it does. ToDo Size depends on var but even with 100 lines a thread it still blocks, even if I remove line which Updates UI, Window still becomes unresponsive, you can't move it etc.

Comment: Sounds to me like some kind of race condition. You have only shown part of your code so its kinda hard to spot it in the code above.

Comment: @Maarten I think I am on to something at  `WebsiteProcessing.ProcessResponse(state);` that does some heavy lifting. It uses IKVM with some java libs, some neural network processing etc. But I still don't understand how can worker thread block UI even if it does expensive stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fault which suprised me very much. It was a custom class with 20-30 regexes used to strip leftover HTML after pulling text with HtmlAgilityPack, what I still don't understand is how can background thread block UI, CPU spikes were never above 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of this call?

```
this.UIThread(() => lblCrawledWebsites.Text = WebsitesCount.ToString());
```

You didn't provide the definition of UIThread, but looks like it's marshalling calls to the UI thread. In this case, if you have many URLs in the ToDo list, it may choke the UI thread.